# Direct3D Level 12_0 missing for GE Force GTX 770

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam

I am on Ubuntu 22.04, running ProtonDB/Steam and the latest (I think) Nvidia driver:

```
Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470
```

When I try to run Far Cry 6 using ProtonDB, the game quits at start complaining that my GPU does not support Direct3D 12 Level feature; however, according to NVIDIA spec my GPU should support DirectX 12.

Running Steam on "Experimental" does not appear to make any difference.

Others are reporting playing the game successfully (https://www.protondb.com/app/2369390) so I am assuming it's something to do with my setup/configuration.

If anyone knows how to get me unblocked, I'd be much grateful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need install driver current version.
See if is available in
[https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
if not try install the nvidia binary driver